# iOS understand crash log from apple

Tags: ios, exception, app-store-connect

- **when I check the app, all works fine (UI & not crash)**, also with release version. any idea what is happening?

**Apple message:**

> We noticed that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 11.4 when we
>   selected the ‘Create Video’ button.

Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance - Hardware Compatibility

We noticed that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 11.4 when we selected the ‘Create Video’ button.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure it runs as expected and displays properly at iPhone resolution on iPad. Even if your app was developed specifically for iPhone, users should still be able to use your app on iPad.

Resources

For information on iOS device screen sizes and resolutions, please review the iOS Human Interface Guidelines as well as Points versus Pixels in the View Programming Guide for iOS.

You may also want to view Size Classes and Core Components and Default Class Sizes for Different Devices for more information about designing apps for multiple screen sizes.

```
{"app_name":"My App","timestamp":"2018-06-11 17:28:32.92 -0700","app_version":"2.0.0","slice_uuid":"********************","adam_id":**********,"build_version":"1.0.0","bundleID":"com.myapp.name","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)","incident_id":"****************************","name":"My App"}
Incident Identifier: ****************************
CrashReporter Key:   **********************
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             My App [2792]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/******************************/My App.app/My App
Identifier:          com.myapp.name
Version:             1.0.0 (2.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.myapp.name [1303]


Date/Time:           2018-06-11 17:28:32.7947 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-06-11 17:27:54.2722 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x185086d8c 0x1842405ec 0x18501f750 0x184f5305c 0x1022c4f80 0x1022c47a0 0x18ec9ee64 0x18ed4ce1c 0x18ed4c2d8 0x18ed4bc14 0x18ed4b6a4 0x18ed3f3a8 0x18ec976f4 0x18920dfec 0x18921217c 0x18917e830 0x1891a6364 0x18ef55598 0x18502e910 0x18502c238 0x18502c884 0x184f4cda8 0x186f31020 0x18ef69758 0x10225b694 0x1849ddfc0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184b0d2ec 0x184aeb000 + 140012
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cae288 0x184cab000 + 12936
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184a7bd0c 0x184a19000 + 404748
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001842162c8 0x184215000 + 4808
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000184216470 0x184215000 + 5232
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001842408d4 0x184238000 + 35028
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018423037c 0x184215000 + 111484
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018422ff78 0x184215000 + 110456
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001842407ac 0x184238000 + 34732
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184f4ce18 0x184f41000 + 48664
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000186f31020 0x186f26000 + 45088
11  UIKit                           0x000000018ef69758 0x18ec4c000 + 3266392
12  My App                          0x000000010225b694 0x10217c000 + 915092
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001849ddfc0 0x1849dd000 + 4032

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184b0dd84 0x184aeb000 + 142724
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cac0a0 0x184cab000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb08 0x184cab000 + 2824

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184aebe08 0x184aeb000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184aebc80 0x184aeb000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018502ee40 0x184f41000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018502c908 0x184f41000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184f4cda8 0x184f41000 + 48552
5   Foundation                      0x00000001859c1674 0x1859b9000 + 34420
6   Foundation                      0x00000001859c151c 0x1859b9000 + 34076
7   UIKit                           0x000000018ec4e768 0x18ec4c000 + 10088
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185ad1efc 0x1859b9000 + 1150716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cad220 0x184cab000 + 8736
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cad110 0x184cab000 + 8464
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb10 0x184cab000 + 2832

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184b0dd84 0x184aeb000 + 142724
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cac0a0 0x184cab000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb08 0x184cab000 + 2824

Thread 4 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184aebe08 0x184aeb000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184aebc80 0x184aeb000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018502ee40 0x184f41000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018502c908 0x184f41000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184f4cda8 0x184f41000 + 48552
5   AVFAudio                        0x000000018aa46398 0x18a9c0000 + 549784
6   AVFAudio                        0x000000018aa707a8 0x18a9c0000 + 722856
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cad220 0x184cab000 + 8736
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cad110 0x184cab000 + 8464
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb10 0x184cab000 + 2832

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184aebe08 0x184aeb000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184aebc80 0x184aeb000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018502ee40 0x184f41000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018502c908 0x184f41000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184f4cda8 0x184f41000 + 48552
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018585a6e0 0x18560a000 + 2426592
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185ad1efc 0x1859b9000 + 1150716
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cad220 0x184cab000 + 8736
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cad110 0x184cab000 + 8464
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb10 0x184cab000 + 2832

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184b0dd84 0x184aeb000 + 142724
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabeb4 0x184cab000 + 3764
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb08 0x184cab000 + 2824

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184b0dd84 0x184aeb000 + 142724
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cac0a0 0x184cab000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb08 0x184cab000 + 2824

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb04 0x184cab000 + 2820

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184cabb04 0x184cab000 + 2820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001c02f3eb7
    x4: 0x0000000184235abd   x5: 0x000000016dc833f0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000184cae110  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000300  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b71bfb40  x21: 0x000000016dc833f0  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b71bfc20
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x00000001c001bf10  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x000000016dc83b30   fp: 0x000000016dc83350   lr: 0x0000000184cae288
    sp: 0x000000016dc83320   pc: 0x0000000184b0d2ec cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: The first thing you must do is to symbolicate the crash log and update your question with that log.